# Laravel 5 login issues with second hash function

Tags: php, authentication, hash, laravel-5, hash-function

I added a hash function to registrar in Laravel 5 using the php hash function:

```
    $password = $data['password'];
    $salt = uniqid(mt_rand(), true);
    $saltpass = $password.$salt;
    $hashed = hash('sha256', $saltpass, false);
    $b_hashed = bcrypt($hashed);

    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => $b_hashed,
        'salt' => $salt,
    ]);
```

This registration function worked, the final password ($b_hashed) and the salt is saved into the database. However, the problem is the login. I tried to hash the user input password with the saved salt, then pass it into the credentials in the postLogin function in AthenticatesAndRegistersUsers.php but it is not working. Here is the code:

```
{
    $request->only('email', 'password');

    $record = \DB::table('users')->where('email', $credentials['email']->get();

    $record = $record[0];

    $pass = $credentials['password'];

    $salt = $record->salt;

    $pass = $pass.$salt;

    $hashed = hash("sha256", $pass, false);

    $credentials = array(
        'email' => $email,
        'password' => $hashed);


    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required|email', 'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    if ($this->auth->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember')))
    {
        return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }

    return redirect($this->loginPath())
                ->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'))
                ->withErrors([
                    'email' => $this->getFailedLoginMessage(),
                ]);
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to implement your own hashing scheme? Laravel will by default calculate a BCrypt hash and automatically creates a salt and stores it with the hash. There is no reason to use a SHA256 with your own salt, SHA is not appropriate to hash passwords.

Comment: I am not implementing my own hashing scheme but to add one more hash level to the existing hashing scheme in Laravel.

Comment: @user4741755 Why? A hash is a hash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your intention is to add extra security, there are better ways to improve the scheme, they would protect from exactly defined threats. Laravel already uses BCrypt by default, this should be good for most purposes.

1. The additional salt (for SHA) won't help, because the job of the salt is already done by the BCrypt salt.
2. The additional SHA-256 will not make the hashing significantly slower, SHA-* is fast and the slowness is already solved by the cost factor of BCrypt.

That leaves the secrecy of the scheme, only an attacker who knows that a SHA-256 was used before calculating the BCrypt hash, can successfully brute-force the passwords. In other word, he needs access to the server to read the code (unless you are building a framework whose code is known anyway).

To add a server side secret, you would better calculate a BCrypt hash, and afterwards encrypt (two-way) the hash with a strong server-side key. This way the key is the secret (not the scheme) and you can exchange it when necessary. I described this more detailed in my [tutorial](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/hash/en/index.php) about securely storing passwords.